# Assign our own IP range to our servers/load balancers at Amazon Web Services?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

In the case that we buy a range of IPs at RIPE. Is there any way to assign those IPs to Amazon EC2 instances or load balancers?

PS: I know that OnApp providers can do it

Comment: I'd open a ticket, or give Amazon a phone call regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. Most likely, however, there is a way to achieve your use case that doesn't require imposing additional costs on every Internet provider.